# How to write await() for multiple promises in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, promise

I m trying to write await for multiple promises, instead of nested functions.

Please take a look at the below code i tried, as it will explain better than me.

```js
var main = async () => {
  // const main_ = await Promise.all(fun1,fun2,fun3);

  // Fun 3
  const fun3 = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => async () => {
      // console.log(1);
      return resolve(await fun2(1));
    });

  // Fun 2
  const fun2 = (value) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => async (value) => {
      value = value + 1;
      // console.log(value);
      return resolve(await fun1(value));
    });

  // Fun 1
  const fun1 = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => (value) => {
      value = value + 1;
      // console.log(value);
      return resolve(value);
    });

  fun3();
};

main();
```

I tried console logging to debut but I m getting nothing in the console.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Promise.all takes an Array as a single argument. 2. `fun1` is a function, `fun1()` is a promise ... you'll want the latter, 3. fun1 etc won't be executable until after they are declared, so the promise.all needs to be after the function declarations, 4. what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

the syntax is wrong, its not `new Promise((resolve) => async () => {})` with 2 arrow, but `new Promise((resolve) => {})` also you can call promise function without `await`

```js
var main = async () => {
  // const main_ = await Promise.all(fun1,fun2,fun3);

  // Fun 3
  const fun3 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    //console.log(1);
    return resolve(fun2(1));
  });

  // Fun 2
  const fun2 = (value) => new Promise(resolve => {
    value = value + 1;
    //console.log(value);
    return resolve(fun1(value));
  });

  // Fun 1
  const fun1 = (value) => new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    value = value + 1;
    console.log('sleep 3 seconds');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
    console.log(value);
    return resolve(value);
  });

  fun3();
};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `await` inside a Promise callback, you can do this:

```
const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
  (async () => {
    const res = await anotherPromise();
    resolve(res);
  })();
});
```

So with this in mind, you can rewrite your functions like this:

```
var main = async () => {
  // const main_ = await Promise.all(fun1,fun2,fun3);

  // Fun 3
  const fun3 = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      (async () => {
        resolve(await fun2(1));
      })();
    });

  // Fun 2
  const fun2 = (value) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      value = value + 1;
      (async () => {
        resolve(await fun1(value));
      })();
    });

  // Fun 1
  const fun1 = (value) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      value = value + 1;
      (async () => {
        resolve(value);
      })();
    });

  return await fun3();
};

// ans: 3
console.log(await main());
```

If you want to do it in pure async/await, you may do this:

```
const main = async () => {
  const fun1 = async (value) => value + 1;
  const fun2 = async (value) => await fun1(value + 1);
  const fun3 = async () => await fun2(1);
  return await fun3();
}
// output: 3
console.log(await main());
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this example works for you.

```js
console.clear();

function wait(ms, data) {
  return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(this, data), ms) );
}

/** 
 * These will be run in series, because we call
 * a function and immediately wait for each result, 
 * so this will finish in 1s.
 */
async function series() {
  return {
    result1: await wait(500, 'seriesTask1'),
    result2: await wait(500, 'seriesTask2'),
  }
}

/** 
 * While here we call the functions first,
 * then wait for the result later, so 
 * this will finish in 500ms.
 */
async function parallel() {
  const task1 = wait(500, 'parallelTask1');
  const task2 = wait(500, 'parallelTask2');

  return {
    result1: await task1,
    result2: await task2,
  }
}

async function taskRunner(fn, label) {
  const startTime = performance.now();
  console.log(`Task ${label} starting...`);
  let result = await fn();
  console.log(`Task ${label} finished in ${ Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime) } miliseconds with,`, result);
}

void taskRunner(series, 'series');
void taskRunner(parallel, 'parallel');
```

Answer (score -1):

fun3() is an async function so you have to put `await` before the call.

```js
var main = async () => {
  // Fun 3
  const fun3 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    //console.log(1);
    return resolve(fun2(1));
  });

  // Fun 2
  const fun2 = (value) => new Promise(resolve => {
    value = value + 1;
    //console.log(value);
    return resolve(fun1(value));
  });

  // Fun 1
  const fun1 = (value) => new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    value = value + 1;
    console.log('sleep 3 seconds');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
    console.log(value);
    return resolve(value);
  });

  await fun3();
};

main();
```